# How to abstract RefreshControl component?

Tags: react-native, controls, refresh

I would like to use RefreshControl with blue loading indicator in multiple places in my app (as a value of refreshControl property of flatlists), and that is why I would like to abstract it, instead of repeating in those places the code below :

```
      <FlatList
        ...
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={isRefreshing}
            onRefresh={this.pullToRefresh}
            colors={[BLUE]}
          />
        }
      />
```

Actually, it doesn't work when I try to abstract it using Component rendering RefreshControl with blue color nor functional component and pass "refreshing" and "onRefresh" props from the parent component, which is a screen rendering FlatList.

Anyone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using `tintColor`
[This link is useful for you](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol#tintcolor)

Comment: Thank you for response. I think I didn't express my problem clearly. The problem is that FlatList doesn't get rendered, and because of that it is impossible to pull RefreshControl component down to refresh. May it be a problem with passing "isRefreshing" state value and function "onRefresh" as a prop to functional component from parent componen which is holding FlatList ?

Comment: ```tintColor``` is only available for iOS platform: https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/refreshcontrol.

Comment: @lffloyd tint color is for all the OS!